# GoogleTrans suddenly stopped working and giving error

Tags: python, google-translate, googletrans

While using googletrans, I am unable to translate my text into any language. I am using python3 to do so.

I have googled many things related to my question and have found many answers on Stack Overflow about it suggesting that there could be a limit issue of characters or IP blocked. But this isn't the case with me. It was working fine some time ago and now it's giving error. And if I ran same code on Google Collab it works fine.

I have tried: clearing the cache; restarting my system twice; deleting the googletrans folder and re-installing. I have also tried the code on Spyder and on Jupyter notebook, but it gives me the same error.

Stack Overflow answers which I found but were of no help are:

1. [Googletrans API error - daily limit or blocked IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672411/googletrans-api-error-daily-limit-or-blocked-ip)
2. [why python googletrans suddenly not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725342/why-python-googletrans-suddenly-not-working)
3. [GoogleTrans API Error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497391/googletrans-api-error-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

This is my code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
trans = translator.translate("ajj bht garmi hai").text
trans
```

I am getting the error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042272/errow-using-googletranslate-package-in-python-expecting-value-line-1-column-1. Seems there could be a problem with the API right now.

Comment: But i used the mentioned code on Google Colab and it worked fine. Its not working on Spyder or on Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine right now, it seems as a problem with the API yesterday.